# zend framework validation error message use label instead field name

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework

Using Zend Framework 1.6. I have a form with a validation:

```
'last_name' => array (
                        'presence' => 'required' 
                )
```

where last_name is the name of the field.

the error message is:

```
Field 'last_name' is required by rule 'last_name', but the field is missing
```

Is possible to show the label value instead the input name? Something like this:

```
Field 'Surname' is required by rule 'Surname', but the field is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by changing the validation messages for that form element.

For example inside the class that extends `Zend_Form` where you're adding your element :

```
$this->addElement('text', 'last_name', array(
'label' => 'Surname',
'filters' => array(
    // set filters here ('StringTrim'... etc
),
// setting validators
'validators' => array(
    array('NotEmpty', true, array(
     'messages' => 'The field Surname is required',//<--your custom message here
    )),
    
//....
),));
```

Comment: Yes, but I I don't want to change my code in many parts. With you tecnique I must change all my validations. I would to change only one setting to change the behavior